# Scripting Tab pages in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs

I have opened new tab (www.blogger.com) from Main.html page by using js:

```
<script>
window.open("https://www.blogger.com");
</script>
```

**So, Now I am in blogger page**

Now what I want to do is automatically cursor (autoscroll) **blogger page** to its end and close that tab .As a result  it would return  me to Main.html page (which is is previous tab).

Again in Main.html tab it should automatically redirect me to another site and autoscroll it to the end ..and repeat the same..

Answer (score 0):

Whatever page you would like to scroll you should use document ready and animate like following code:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$("body")[0].scrollHeight}, function() {
    window.close(); // this is automatically close the tab when the scroll is completed
  });
});
```

When the animation completed, the page will be automatically close by using `window.close();`

You can change the animation effect or scrolling speed. Please have a look to the documentation. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Demo:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $("body")[0].scrollHeight
  }, function() {
    window.close();
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quis lacus magna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut suscipit nulla nec odio scelerisque, malesuada sodales ligula sollicitudin. Phasellus rhoncus a arcu sit amet
    lobortis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin et tortor nec leo dapibus feugiat. Cras interdum turpis eu posuere varius. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer ut ultrices purus.
  </p>
  <p>
    Praesent laoreet a elit vel vestibulum. Suspendisse faucibus mi sit amet rutrum ornare. Maecenas interdum, tellus eget facilisis tempor, justo justo vestibulum nibh, sed fermentum felis odio ut purus. Sed aliquet urna at risus tincidunt, at consequat
    arcu efficitur. Etiam maximus lacus eu egestas cursus. Praesent eget varius lorem. Proin mi lorem, imperdiet at arcu quis, aliquam sollicitudin lacus. Cras tincidunt porta arcu, eu bibendum nibh molestie pulvinar. Nullam aliquam lorem orci. Nulla
    vitae neque accumsan, egestas nibh et, dapibus quam.
  </p>
  <p>
    Curabitur interdum scelerisque orci a commodo. Donec suscipit mauris non neque mattis, id ornare ligula finibus. Vivamus placerat, nisi nec cursus lobortis, sem odio fringilla neque, vitae porta purus ipsum eu neque. Maecenas pretium lorem lacinia mi
    accumsan, sit amet interdum felis tempus. Mauris at ante vel purus lobortis fringilla quis vel nibh. Curabitur a nunc sit amet metus egestas varius. Ut vel odio ex. Donec lacinia convallis euismod.
  </p>
  <p>
    Cras dictum viverra eros in rutrum. Nunc ut dictum neque, eget imperdiet massa. Integer quis rutrum arcu. Maecenas quis rhoncus augue. Sed enim metus, fringilla eu nulla nec, eleifend lobortis dolor. Maecenas auctor libero vel arcu convallis fermentum.
    Sed turpis tellus, dignissim nec mattis non, pharetra gravida dui. Etiam viverra dolor ut arcu gravida, non interdum lacus interdum. Morbi malesuada magna ullamcorper, iaculis nisi at, consequat mi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam et pellentesque
    purus, nec elementum elit. Sed venenatis iaculis malesuada.
  </p>
  <p>
    Integer malesuada blandit odio in vehicula. Ut vitae urna quis velit sodales lacinia. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pellentesque quam in mollis tristique. Aliquam euismod vulputate
    leo quis venenatis. In facilisis mi eget nisi convallis maximus. Sed placerat nec risus id molestie. Quisque pharetra, elit et varius placerat, libero ligula molestie turpis, nec faucibus mauris mauris quis ante. Morbi id placerat sem.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quis lacus magna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut suscipit nulla nec odio scelerisque, malesuada sodales ligula sollicitudin. Phasellus rhoncus a arcu sit amet
    lobortis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin et tortor nec leo dapibus feugiat. Cras interdum turpis eu posuere varius. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer ut ultrices purus.
  </p>
  <p>
    Praesent laoreet a elit vel vestibulum. Suspendisse faucibus mi sit amet rutrum ornare. Maecenas interdum, tellus eget facilisis tempor, justo justo vestibulum nibh, sed fermentum felis odio ut purus. Sed aliquet urna at risus tincidunt, at consequat
    arcu efficitur. Etiam maximus lacus eu egestas cursus. Praesent eget varius lorem. Proin mi lorem, imperdiet at arcu quis, aliquam sollicitudin lacus. Cras tincidunt porta arcu, eu bibendum nibh molestie pulvinar. Nullam aliquam lorem orci. Nulla
    vitae neque accumsan, egestas nibh et, dapibus quam.
  </p>
  <p>
    Curabitur interdum scelerisque orci a commodo. Donec suscipit mauris non neque mattis, id ornare ligula finibus. Vivamus placerat, nisi nec cursus lobortis, sem odio fringilla neque, vitae porta purus ipsum eu neque. Maecenas pretium lorem lacinia mi
    accumsan, sit amet interdum felis tempus. Mauris at ante vel purus lobortis fringilla quis vel nibh. Curabitur a nunc sit amet metus egestas varius. Ut vel odio ex. Donec lacinia convallis euismod.
  </p>
  <p>
    Cras dictum viverra eros in rutrum. Nunc ut dictum neque, eget imperdiet massa. Integer quis rutrum arcu. Maecenas quis rhoncus augue. Sed enim metus, fringilla eu nulla nec, eleifend lobortis dolor. Maecenas auctor libero vel arcu convallis fermentum.
    Sed turpis tellus, dignissim nec mattis non, pharetra gravida dui. Etiam viverra dolor ut arcu gravida, non interdum lacus interdum. Morbi malesuada magna ullamcorper, iaculis nisi at, consequat mi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam et pellentesque
    purus, nec elementum elit. Sed venenatis iaculis malesuada.
  </p>
  <p>
    Integer malesuada blandit odio in vehicula. Ut vitae urna quis velit sodales lacinia. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pellentesque quam in mollis tristique. Aliquam euismod vulputate
    leo quis venenatis. In facilisis mi eget nisi convallis maximus. Sed placerat nec risus id molestie. Quisque pharetra, elit et varius placerat, libero ligula molestie turpis, nec faucibus mauris mauris quis ante. Morbi id placerat sem.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quis lacus magna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut suscipit nulla nec odio scelerisque, malesuada sodales ligula sollicitudin. Phasellus rhoncus a arcu sit amet
    lobortis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin et tortor nec leo dapibus feugiat. Cras interdum turpis eu posuere varius. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer ut ultrices purus.
  </p>
  <p>
    Praesent laoreet a elit vel vestibulum. Suspendisse faucibus mi sit amet rutrum ornare. Maecenas interdum, tellus eget facilisis tempor, justo justo vestibulum nibh, sed fermentum felis odio ut purus. Sed aliquet urna at risus tincidunt, at consequat
    arcu efficitur. Etiam maximus lacus eu egestas cursus. Praesent eget varius lorem. Proin mi lorem, imperdiet at arcu quis, aliquam sollicitudin lacus. Cras tincidunt porta arcu, eu bibendum nibh molestie pulvinar. Nullam aliquam lorem orci. Nulla
    vitae neque accumsan, egestas nibh et, dapibus quam.
  </p>
  <p>
    Curabitur interdum scelerisque orci a commodo. Donec suscipit mauris non neque mattis, id ornare ligula finibus. Vivamus placerat, nisi nec cursus lobortis, sem odio fringilla neque, vitae porta purus ipsum eu neque. Maecenas pretium lorem lacinia mi
    accumsan, sit amet interdum felis tempus. Mauris at ante vel purus lobortis fringilla quis vel nibh. Curabitur a nunc sit amet metus egestas varius. Ut vel odio ex. Donec lacinia convallis euismod.
  </p>
  <p>
    Cras dictum viverra eros in rutrum. Nunc ut dictum neque, eget imperdiet massa. Integer quis rutrum arcu. Maecenas quis rhoncus augue. Sed enim metus, fringilla eu nulla nec, eleifend lobortis dolor. Maecenas auctor libero vel arcu convallis fermentum.
    Sed turpis tellus, dignissim nec mattis non, pharetra gravida dui. Etiam viverra dolor ut arcu gravida, non interdum lacus interdum. Morbi malesuada magna ullamcorper, iaculis nisi at, consequat mi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam et pellentesque
    purus, nec elementum elit. Sed venenatis iaculis malesuada.
  </p>
  <p>
    Integer malesuada blandit odio in vehicula. Ut vitae urna quis velit sodales lacinia. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pellentesque quam in mollis tristique. Aliquam euismod vulputate
    leo quis venenatis. In facilisis mi eget nisi convallis maximus. Sed placerat nec risus id molestie. Quisque pharetra, elit et varius placerat, libero ligula molestie turpis, nec faucibus mauris mauris quis ante. Morbi id placerat sem.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quis lacus magna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut suscipit nulla nec odio scelerisque, malesuada sodales ligula sollicitudin. Phasellus rhoncus a arcu sit amet
    lobortis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin et tortor nec leo dapibus feugiat. Cras interdum turpis eu posuere varius. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer ut ultrices purus.
  </p>
  <p>
    Praesent laoreet a elit vel vestibulum. Suspendisse faucibus mi sit amet rutrum ornare. Maecenas interdum, tellus eget facilisis tempor, justo justo vestibulum nibh, sed fermentum felis odio ut purus. Sed aliquet urna at risus tincidunt, at consequat
    arcu efficitur. Etiam maximus lacus eu egestas cursus. Praesent eget varius lorem. Proin mi lorem, imperdiet at arcu quis, aliquam sollicitudin lacus. Cras tincidunt porta arcu, eu bibendum nibh molestie pulvinar. Nullam aliquam lorem orci. Nulla
    vitae neque accumsan, egestas nibh et, dapibus quam.
  </p>
  <p>
    Curabitur interdum scelerisque orci a commodo. Donec suscipit mauris non neque mattis, id ornare ligula finibus. Vivamus placerat, nisi nec cursus lobortis, sem odio fringilla neque, vitae porta purus ipsum eu neque. Maecenas pretium lorem lacinia mi
    accumsan, sit amet interdum felis tempus. Mauris at ante vel purus lobortis fringilla quis vel nibh. Curabitur a nunc sit amet metus egestas varius. Ut vel odio ex. Donec lacinia convallis euismod.
  </p>
  <p>
    Cras dictum viverra eros in rutrum. Nunc ut dictum neque, eget imperdiet massa. Integer quis rutrum arcu. Maecenas quis rhoncus augue. Sed enim metus, fringilla eu nulla nec, eleifend lobortis dolor. Maecenas auctor libero vel arcu convallis fermentum.
    Sed turpis tellus, dignissim nec mattis non, pharetra gravida dui. Etiam viverra dolor ut arcu gravida, non interdum lacus interdum. Morbi malesuada magna ullamcorper, iaculis nisi at, consequat mi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam et pellentesque
    purus, nec elementum elit. Sed venenatis iaculis malesuada.
  </p>
  <p>
    Integer malesuada blandit odio in vehicula. Ut vitae urna quis velit sodales lacinia. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pellentesque quam in mollis tristique. Aliquam euismod vulputate
    leo quis venenatis. In facilisis mi eget nisi convallis maximus. Sed placerat nec risus id molestie. Quisque pharetra, elit et varius placerat, libero ligula molestie turpis, nec faucibus mauris mauris quis ante. Morbi id placerat sem.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quis lacus magna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut suscipit nulla nec odio scelerisque, malesuada sodales ligula sollicitudin. Phasellus rhoncus a arcu sit amet
    lobortis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin et tortor nec leo dapibus feugiat. Cras interdum turpis eu posuere varius. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer ut ultrices purus.
  </p>
  <p>
    Praesent laoreet a elit vel vestibulum. Suspendisse faucibus mi sit amet rutrum ornare. Maecenas interdum, tellus eget facilisis tempor, justo justo vestibulum nibh, sed fermentum felis odio ut purus. Sed aliquet urna at risus tincidunt, at consequat
    arcu efficitur. Etiam maximus lacus eu egestas cursus. Praesent eget varius lorem. Proin mi lorem, imperdiet at arcu quis, aliquam sollicitudin lacus. Cras tincidunt porta arcu, eu bibendum nibh molestie pulvinar. Nullam aliquam lorem orci. Nulla
    vitae neque accumsan, egestas nibh et, dapibus quam.
  </p>
  <p>
    Curabitur interdum scelerisque orci a commodo. Donec suscipit mauris non neque mattis, id ornare ligula finibus. Vivamus placerat, nisi nec cursus lobortis, sem odio fringilla neque, vitae porta purus ipsum eu neque. Maecenas pretium lorem lacinia mi
    accumsan, sit amet interdum felis tempus. Mauris at ante vel purus lobortis fringilla quis vel nibh. Curabitur a nunc sit amet metus egestas varius. Ut vel odio ex. Donec lacinia convallis euismod.
  </p>
  <p>
    Cras dictum viverra eros in rutrum. Nunc ut dictum neque, eget imperdiet massa. Integer quis rutrum arcu. Maecenas quis rhoncus augue. Sed enim metus, fringilla eu nulla nec, eleifend lobortis dolor. Maecenas auctor libero vel arcu convallis fermentum.
    Sed turpis tellus, dignissim nec mattis non, pharetra gravida dui. Etiam viverra dolor ut arcu gravida, non interdum lacus interdum. Morbi malesuada magna ullamcorper, iaculis nisi at, consequat mi. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aliquam et pellentesque
    purus, nec elementum elit. Sed venenatis iaculis malesuada.
  </p>
  <p>
    Integer malesuada blandit odio in vehicula. Ut vitae urna quis velit sodales lacinia. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Proin pellentesque quam in mollis tristique. Aliquam euismod vulputate
    leo quis venenatis. In facilisis mi eget nisi convallis maximus. Sed placerat nec risus id molestie. Quisque pharetra, elit et varius placerat, libero ligula molestie turpis, nec faucibus mauris mauris quis ante. Morbi id placerat sem.
  </p>
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam quis lacus magna. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Ut suscipit nulla nec odio scelerisque, malesuada sodales ligula sollicitudin. Phasellus rhoncus a arcu sit amet
    lobortis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Proin et tortor nec leo dapibus feugiat. Cras interdum turpis eu posuere varius. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Integer ut ultrices purus.
  </p>
  <p>
    Praesent laoreet a elit vel vestibulum. Suspendisse faucibus mi sit amet rutrum ornare. Maecenas interdum, tellus eget facilisis tempor, justo justo vestibulum nibh, sed fermentum felis odio ut purus. Sed aliquet urna at risus tincidunt, at consequat
    arcu efficitur. Etiam maximus lacus eu egestas cursus. Praesent eget varius lorem. Proin mi lorem, imperdiet at arcu quis, aliquam sollicitudin lacus. Cras tincidunt porta arcu, eu bibendum nibh molestie pulvinar. Nullam aliquam lorem orci. Nulla
    vitae neque accumsan, egestas nibh et, dapibus quam.
  </p>
  <p>
    Curabitur interdum scelerisque orci a commodo. Donec suscipit mauris non neque mattis, id ornare ligula finibus. Vivamus placerat, nisi nec cursus lobortis, sem odio fringilla neque, vitae porta purus ipsum eu neque. Maecenas pretium lorem lacinia mi
    accumsan, sit amet interdum felis tempus. Mauris at ante vel purus lobortis fringilla quis vel nibh. Curabitur a nunc sit amet metus egestas varius. Ut vel odio ex. Donec lacinia convallis euismod.
  </p>

  <body>

</html>
```